# Unable to hot deploy from SpringSource Tool Suite 2.8.1 to GlassFish 3.1

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jsp, glassfish

I am unable to publish JSPs or other static file changes without a full server restart. This works fine from NetBeans using the same server installation. For the time being I've disabled automatic publishing because my server would be restarting more often than it's available.

To reiterate the versions from the title:

- **IDE**: SpringSource Tool Suite 2.8.1
- **Server**: GlassFish 3.1

Thanks for any help! Please let me know if any other information would be helpful to diagnose this problem.

Edit: Switched to Tomcat 7 after unsuccessfully trying a clean install of vanilla Eclipse with GlassFish.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me.  I think you may want to re-enable automatic publishing.  If you are concerned with server restarts, that is a separate configuration within STS.  To disable this feature, double click on the server, go to the modules tab and disable auto-reload for you installed module.

Comment: I don't have a modules tab for the GlassFish. The Tomcat one has it, but I don't have the problem with Tomcat. I'm using the server adapter Oracle GlassFish Server Tools version 1.7.3.201106220649.